# Does personalization require a specific license?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, personalization

I'm looking at the list of licenses and wondering if there is one specific license that enables personalization. If so, which license should I be looking for?

Using Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 151127)

[image: Licenses menu option]

[image: List of active licenses]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have Sitecore.xDB.base license.

> Sitecore 8.1 now requires a license with the “Sitecore.xDB.base” key
>   to enable all features of the Experience Platform. If your license
>   file does not contain this key, Sitecore will default to Experience
>   Management (CMS-only) mode. Any customers or partners with a license
>   to Experience Platform should contact their account manager or login
>   to SPN if they are missing this key.

See https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/Sitecore_81/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_81_Initial_Release.aspx

Comment: I'm using Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 151127). I should have clarified in the post. Does that change anything?

Comment: I don't think you need Sitecore.xDB.Base license in Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 151127). If personalization is not working, you should check if xDB is properly installed or if you have Sitecore CMS-only mode enabled. Check https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/configure_experience_management for more details.