# Is A/B test avaible in Experience Manager?

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile, experience-optimization

Is A/B test (content,component and page) and related analytics data available in the base Sitecore license, Sitecore Experience Manager?

Answer (score 2):

#### No

You essentially need the license `Sitecore.xDB.Base` for that functionality. This is included in the Sitecore Experience Platform license (XP).

More information here: [Sitecore XP 8.0 and greater product license overview](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/911240)

Comment: it's strange because in my license detail there is Sitecore.xDB.Base. 
My client told me he bought Sitecore Experience management, I'm missing something ?
Is Sitecore.xDB.Base needed to run only A/B test  without analytics?

Comment: Well I notice you changed the Sitecore Experience Management (a valid Sitecore license name) to not include the capital M.  If I (or anyone) is to answer questions about a license, a correct name would be required. That said - if you do indeed have `Sitecore.xDB.Base` in your license then - as best as I am aware - personalization with all the bells and whistles will work for you.

Comment: See also: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/does-personalization-require-a-specific-license